# Connecting Snowflake as a consumer to a JDBC endpoint

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to find a way for a Snowflake instance to connect to and consume from a JDBC connection. I only am able to find in my google-fu results that go the opposite direction. I dont want my JDBC connection to read Snowflake, I want to read my JDBC connection FROM snowflake. Essentially I have an external data source that has a JDBC endpoint I can hit and I want to query its data to leverage into my own tables in Snowflake.

Anything out there? I also have ODBC capabilities on this endpoint.

Comment: Are you trying to load the data into Snowflake tables, where it is subsequently available to be queried, or are you trying to access the data in real-time as part of a query (or some different scenario)?

Comment: Primarily to load into other tables. Would be nice for the ability to query directly from the jdbc connection however.

Comment: You can load data using any ETL tool that can use JDBC connectors and can connect to Snowflake - either a commercial package or one you’ve created yourself in e.g, Python. Unfortunately, recommending software is off topic for this forum. You can’t query data directly from Snowflake via a JDBC connection unless, possibly, you could write a function that did this - however the performance would likely be terrible compared to querying data in Snowflake so I can only imagine this being a usable solution if you were querying small datasets

Comment: Excellent, thanks @NickW! Appreciate the responses.